# Identity 2.0 CodeFirst Migration to Use Stored Procedures

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-identity-2

I'm trying to move my existing ASP.Net Identity Framework project across to use Stored Procedures on the existing models.  I have migrations already enabled, and have an existing database which is basically the stock/standard the Identity builds (few extra columns here and there).  I have tried to enable the Stored Procedures via the `DbContext`:

```
public class IdentityDbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users").MapToStoredProcedures();
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("Roles").MapToStoredProcedures();
    }
}
```

Then I generate the migration:

```
Add-Migration -Name AddStoredProcedures
```

And apply the migration:

```
Update-Database
```

Now when I try to run my application I am getting the exception when it attempts :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The model backing the 'IdentityDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269)."}
```

AFAICT, I ran the update correctly (`__migrationhistory` table contains the name of the migration).  Looking at my database, the stored procedures are added.  Why does the framework not recognize it?